# How to find all item ids of items that can be found on the market board?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In *Final Fantasy XIV*, each item has an in-game item ID. In the market board, you can filter items by item ID. They all seem to be numbered in between a rough range from 1 to 37000. However, not all ints are linked to in-game items and not all of them will be available on the market board. Is there a list somewhere of all the item IDs I might find on the market board?

Comment: Hi. These questions seem more appropriate on [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) since you're asking about API. Here on Arqade we discuss only about gameplay, and not game development.

Comment: I rephrased the question to be more player-based.  All items in this game have a game item id.  I want to find a list of all the items sellable on the market board and find the id of each one.

Comment: I/I'll consider this a gaming/game specific utility, which is on-topic as listed in our [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://universalis.app/docs/index.html has this info under the following API with all marketable items.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://universalis.app/api/marketable' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain'
```

However note that not all marketable items will actively have sales on the ah.  There seems to be around 13,500 items that can be sold on the ah, but not all of them will be up on a single market board.  In my studies, I found only around 1,500 different items were on my market board at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool on GitHub for this called [**FFXIV Lodestone Item ID**](https://github.com/Asvel/ffxiv-lodestone-item-id). As of writing, it is still maintained by the developer. Here's the jist of it:

> This repo provides a list of Eorzea Database items' id. ... lodestone-item-id.txt contains one id per line, and the line number (starts at 1) is corresponding to its in-game id.

Alternatively, you can look it up yourself.

You'll have to find a way to extract a .csv file containing the directory of items in the game. Once you have it, I imagine you can do a quick <kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and look up your item from there, where all its metadata is stored near its name, including the item ID, which can be anywhere from 1-5 digits long.

Things start to get a little blurrier when it comes to breaking the Terms of Service, though, and you're at risk of getting your account banned, as datamining can potentially be used to cheat or otherwise play unfairly, so do this at your own risk!